# Not able to do Javascript Regular Expression in Dynatrace

Tags: javascript, dynatrace

$("div:contains('Cre­ate Pur­chase Req­ui­si­tion')").click();

I have used above Javascript code to click on an element , but the is not working as there are few extra characters (Like &) in between the innertext 'Cre­ate Pur­chase Req­ui­si­tion'. I have attached the Image for your reference. Please help me to regularize the above expression so that it will handle any extra characters that comes in between after Website Upgrade.

Thanks in advance,

Maher.

[FLP Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkRoN.png)

Comment: Any reason you don't just add the soft hyphens in the text search? They can be input as `\xad` in a JS string.

Comment: I guess that you should be targeting the button element instead of a `div` or `span` inside of it. Could you provide some of the HTML code as well?

Comment: You should set an `id` or find another way to achieve this. This solution has poor performances and will surely not work for all kind of content.